# After typing node server.js nothing happens

Tags: node.js

I am trying to start server.js using node but for some reason it's not working.

`nodejs` and `mongodb` are installed. `socket.io` also installed.

After typing `node server.js` nothing happens.

server.js

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = require('socket.io').listen(4000).sockets;//listen socket 4000 port

console.log("asd")

// connect to mongo
mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('mongodb  connected');
});
```

[image]

`node --version` returns v9.4.0

Comment: When I run your code I get your console logs correctly. Check your mongo installation. :)

Comment: mongo is installed correctly i can connect it using compass also mongod is listening for connection

Comment: Does node work at all? What if you type `node -e 'console.log("hello")'`?